# possible to precompute ggplot histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Is it possible to precompute values for ggplot histogram? Computing a number of histograms is really slowing down my ShinyR app, so I'd like to find a way to cache histograms so they are only computed once for a given set of parameters. I checked the [docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_histogram.html) but didn't see anything about this. Apologies if I missed something, but could someone point me to documentation about how to do this, or tell me that it's not possible?

Comment: You can save plots as images and display the right image at the right time.

Comment: @Gregor but to plot I need renderPlot and to load an image I need renderImage. Is there a way to seamlessly pivot between these? Seems I would have to spend a lot of time jerry-rigging something to either load a plot or an image, no? This could get quite messy.

Comment: `x <- hist(..., plot = F)` gives you the breaks and counts. You can use `geom_bar(..., stat = "identity")` to plot that.

Comment: If you're taking this approach, I would pre-generate all plots and save all as images, then there's no switching. If you do up a small reproducible example (say, 2 or 3 plots), then we could do some testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

n <- 400

server <- function(input, output) {
  cachedData <<- list()

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "data1" = list("name"="dataset1", "data"=data.frame("x"=runif(n),"y"=runif(n)), "plot"=NULL),
           "data2" = list("name"="dataset2", "data"=data.frame("x"=runif(n),"y"=runif(n)), "plot"=NULL),
           "data3" = list("name"="dataset3", "data"=data.frame("x"=runif(n),"y"=runif(n)), "plot"=NULL))
  })

  observeEvent(input$run,{
    d               <- datasetInput()
    # If dataset cached
    if ( d$name %in% names(cachedData) ){

    }
    # Else cache dataset
    else{
      cachedData[[d$name]] <<- d
    }


    # See if data is loaded
    if ( is.null( cachedData[[d$name]]$plot ) ){
      print("Creating Plot")
      cachedData[[d$name]]$plot <<- ggplot(data=d$data,aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram(stat="bin")
    }
    else{
      print("Loading plot")
    }

    # Else save data
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ cachedData[[d$name]]$plot})
  })

}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:", 
              choices = c("data1", "data2", "data3")),
  plotOutput("plot"),
  actionButton('run','Generate Plot')
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The cachedData list can then be loaded and saved with the `load` and  `save` functions.